# How to loop over all elements of an array inside an object in array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
myArrayOfObjects = [
  0: {
    title: 'title 1',
    ids: ['90b7f1804642', 'ffa339e9aed7']
  },
  1: {
    title: 'test 2',
    ids: ['99472a9cb432', 'ec3d70ea6ef8']
  }
];
```

I want to check each of the values in ids array if they match an id I have outside. This is what I came up with:

```
myArrayOfObjects.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item.ids[index] === this.myId) {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
    }
})
```

But it does not go through all of the values in ids array. What is the appropriate way to solve this?

Comment: `let myArrayOfObjects = [0: 'value']` is not how you create arrays (you're also missing some quotes)

Comment: 1. the "ArrayObject" haven't a correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` you're using there is the index of the current item that the forEach is on, not an index in the ids array. You could do another forEach on that ids array, or just a .includes looks nicer, I think:

```
myArrayOfObjects.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item.ids.includes(this.myId)) {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array inside the array

```
myArrayOfObjects.forEach((item) => {
    item.ids.forEach((id) => {
        if(id === this.myId) {
          console.log('SUCCESS');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Problem is OP's `myArrayOfObjects` is not a valid array

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying, but I'm assuming he copy pasted it from a browser console that shows the indexes as though they were keys

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
myArrayOfObjects.forEach((item, index) => {

  if(item.ids.includes(this.myId)) {
  //or if(item.ids.indexOf(this.myId) > -1) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  }
})
```